# jQueryUI Sortable: how do sort multiple lists without nesting

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm attempting to sort multiple lists distinguished by selector (".fruit" and ".color"), but without putting them into separate HTML containers.

```
<ul id="sortable">
    <li class='fruit'>orange</li>
    <li class='fruit'>apple</li>
    <li class='color'>yellow</li>
    <li class='color'>red</li>
</ul>
```

Please see this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/s9kqLh58/

Thus, elements of each list should be siblings, but separately sortable based on the item selector. The effect should be that the 2 types of list items (colors and fruits) should be non-mixable - the colors would always be at the bottom, and the fruits would always be at the top.

As you can see by the fiddle, the colors are sortable, but not the fruits.

Is there a way to do this with jQueryUI, or does anyone know of an extension to jQueryUI sortable that might permit what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this:

```
<ul id="sortable">
 <div class="fruit">
   <li>orange</li>
   <li>apple</li>
 </div>
 <div class="color">
   <li>yellow</li>
   <li>red</li>
 </div>
</ul>
```

And in your Javascript:

```
  $(function() {
    $( ".fruit" ).sortable();
    $( ".fruit" ).disableSelection();
    $( ".color" ).sortable();
    $( ".color" ).disableSelection();
  });
```

Check out this [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s9kqLh58/12/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, this is not the answer. The fruit items that the color items should be independently sortable, as if they were in separate lists. Thus, it should be impossible to re-arrange the items so that fruit and colors are mixed.

Comment: Well that is possible but you have to edit your HTML for that. You can't do that with plain javascript(well actually you can but you would need tons and tons of code for it). Check out my edited code.

Comment: Yes, this is ordinarily how one would do it. However, I'm attempting to have 2 sortable lists without separating them into separate HTML containers.

Comment: Hmm oke, i can't help you any further with that. i hope you find your answer :)